# Showing menu when right clicking on a item of a tree view

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, treeview

I have a treeview and I wanted to add right click support for the different items. This is how I did it:

http://jsfiddle.net/doonot/xWjSz/

The menu is shown only for the first root module (after right click), but not for the rest of the root modules. Can you tell me what I have to change, in order to get the menu for all root modules?

Thanks a lot, I much appreciate your answer.

Comment: Hiya there, I can give you a very simple jsfiddle will that work for you it will capture your right click? please, let me know if that suits you bruv will update the answer using tree view, have a nice one :) cheerios!

Comment: Yes that would be very nice. Give me one minute, and I will add a part of my tree view above! Btw, I am using jquery-treeview.

Comment: Saweet gimme 2 mins! cheerios bruv!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiya **Please see this demo** http://jsfiddle.net/hYJPv/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/hYJPv/ (Fixed the issue) **or** diff approach here http://jsfiddle.net/UeqBk/for_Dooonot_from_Tats_innit/

on `rightclick` you will get an alert.

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // If you want to disable showing the context menu when right clicking
    // on the document, the code below would do the trick.
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e)
    {
        alert('right click capture');
        return false;
    }); 

    var $tree = $("#tree").kendoTreeView(
    {
        select: function (event)
        {
            var $item = $(event.node);
            console.log( $item );
            alert( "selected" );
        }
    });


    // Find the item you want to select...
    var $selected = $('#selected');
    var $treePath = $selected.parentsUntil($tree, "li");

    var treeView = $tree.data('kendoTreeView');

    // Expand the tree in order to show the selected item
    treeView.expand( $treePath );

    // Gotta make both calls...
    treeView.select( $selected );
    treeView.trigger( 'select', {node: $selected} );
});
​
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But I am not sure if that is really what I need. I am able to capture the right click, and the menu is even shown, BUT only for the first item in the treeview. It does not work for the rest of the items. I don't know, how to do that. Do you know?

Comment: @dooonot no probs bruv, you mean in the example I have given or in your sample? sorry if this sound bit dense :Pjust making it sure that I get it right what you mean! cheerios!

Comment: In the example I provided. I am actually using this [tutorial](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/22/create-simple-jquery-right-click-cross-browser-vertical-menu/).

Comment: @dooonot saweet! aha okies wait will give a shot, gimme 10.

Comment: Yo @dooonot is this what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/Mhq2j/2/ let me know bruv B-) ! cheers

Comment: Please see my example. Right click on the first (it works), right click on the second, it doesnt work :) http://jsfiddle.net/doonot/xWjSz/

Comment: Saweet just an observation: you know that you got multiple tags with same `id` which is HTML wise wrong ? :)) i mean `id=rightclickarea` yep taking a look now.

Comment: That's why you have to help me :) It has to be very flexible, because I have hundereds of modules and items!

Comment: @dooonot **AND RESOLVED :)** magic!!  http://jsfiddle.net/hYJPv/  or this http://jsfiddle.net/hYJPv/1/ updating my answer and don't forget to up vote and accept my answer

Comment: God damn, that's sweet man. Thanks a lot. Now following you on twitter :) See you there and muchas gracias :)

Comment: @dooonot yea some dudes forced me join twitter lol; I aint that regular but good to see you there and no problems at all! have a good one, cheerios!